# Docker logs, stderr

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash, fluentd

Is it possible to separate docker logs between stderr \ stdout? Via fluentd\logstash etc.
The ultimate goal - sending logs to elasticsearch and filter it by  stderr\stdout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to separate docker logs into stdout processing and stderr processing in fluentd side, you can use rewite-tag-filter plugin with `source` value.

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_rewrite_tag_filter

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a duplicate of

```
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7440
```

Here is an example:

```
$ docker run -d --name foo busybox ls abcd
$ docker logs foo > stdout.log 2>stderr.log
$ cat stdout.log
$ cat stderr.log
ls: abcd: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked at json docker logs and really - it has "stream" param And now i can do something with this.

Answer (score 0):

See latest from [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7440) @Opal posted.

```
# stdout
docker logs container_name 2>/dev/null

# stderr
docker logs container_name >/dev/null
```